# How to get a String from C code in Android NDK?

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

I am working on Android ndk application in which I want to get the String from my C code like this we do in our Java code for example:

```
Stringa fName = "ABCDE";
Stringa fMiddleName = "QWWER";
Stringa fLastName = "ZXCVV";
```

I want to write this code in C and want to get the values from this code to my Java Code. Right now, my code to get some long values is given below.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <com_testing_ndk_FibLib.h>

static jlong fib(jlong n){
        return n<=0 ? 0 : n==1 ? 1: fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_fibNR
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jlong n)
{
        return fib(n);
}
/*
 * Class:     com_testing_ndk_FibLib
 * Method:    fibNI
 * Signature: (J)J
 */
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_fibNI
(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jlong n)
{

    jlong previous = -1;
    jlong result = 1;
    jlong i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        jlong sum = result + previous;
        previous = result;
        result = sum;
    }
    return result;

}
```

My Java Code:

```
public class FibLib {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("com_testing_ndk_FibLib");
    }

    public static long fibJR(long n){
        return n<=0 ? 0 : n==1 ? 1: fibJR(n - 1) + fibJR(n - 2);
    }
    public native static long fibNR(long n);


    public static long fibJI(long n){
        long previous = -1;
        long result = 1;
        for (long i=0;i<n;i++){
            long sum = result + previous;
            previous = result;
            result = sum;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public native static long fibNI(long n);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this to create a Java String in C++

```
jstring str = env->NewStringUTF("Test");
```

**Java**

```
public native static String getTestString();
```

**C++**

```
extern "C" {
  JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_fibNI_getTestString(JNIEnv* env, jclass jclazz) {
    jstring str = env->NewStringUTF("Test");
    return str;
  }
}
```

**C**

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_fibNI_getTestString(JNIEnv* env, jclass jclazz) {
    jstring str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
    return str;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your. Is it for C or only for C++ ?? Because here i am using it for C.

Comment: There is not much difference between C/C++. Why are you using C instead of C++?